# sorting data from an array on php

Tags: php, shopify

i'm deploying a shipping service to shopify using a webhook to get this data converted in json, i trying to send only the fields name, quantity, sku and id in a table.
i'm using foreach function to make it but no results.

Grettings!

```
[fulfillments] => Array
   (
       [0] => stdClass Object
           (
               [line_items] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => stdClass Object
                           (
                               [fulfillment_service] => manual
                               [fulfillment_status] => fulfilled
                               [gift_card] => 
                               [grams] => 2000
                               [id] => 470651995
                               [price] => 200.00
                               [product_id] => 304163215
                               [quantity] => 1
                               [requires_shipping] => 1
                               [sku] => 123456789
                               [taxable] => 
                               [title] => Product 1
                               [variant_id] => 709836495
                               [variant_title] => 
                               [vendor] => kkk
                               [name] => Product 1
                           )
                       [1] => stdClass Object
                           (
                               [fulfillment_service] => manual
                               [fulfillment_status] => fulfilled
                               [gift_card] => 
                               [grams] => 2000
                               [id] => 470651995
                               [price] => 200.00
                               [product_id] => 304163215
                               [quantity] => 3
                               [requires_shipping] => 1
                               [sku] => 123456789
                               [taxable] => 
                               [title] => Product 2
                               [variant_id] => 709836495
                               [variant_title] => 
                               [vendor] => kkk
                               [name] => Product 2
                           )


                   )

           )

   )
```

Comment: how r u you using the foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$your_array = json_decode(json_encode($your_array), true); 
    //it will casts from StdClass to an array
$your_array = $your_array['fulfillments'];
$result_array = array();

$yaCnt = count($your_array);
for($i = 0; $i < $yaCnt; ++$i)
{
    $items = $yaCnt[$i]['line_items'];
    $iCnt = count($items);
    for($j = 0; $j < $iCnt; ++$j)
    {
        $result_array[] = array(
            'name'     => $items[$j]['name'],
            'quantity' => $items[$j]['quantity'],
            'sku'      => $items[$j]['sku'],
            'id'       => $items[$j]['id']
        );
    }
}

print_r($result_array);
```

Comment: great idea! `json_decode(json_encode($your_array), true);` :)

Comment: @rcro yeah, it works great if you have an objects mixed with arrays. In usual casts from object to array better to use explicit type cast `(array)$var`

Comment: @fiction thanks a lot, it's just what i want do it! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `foreach()`, I have assumed you store all the initial data in the variable `$fulfillments`

```
$items = array(); 

foreach($fulfillments[0]->line_items as $item)
{
    $items[] = array(
        "name"      => $item->name,
        "quantity"  => $item->quantity, 
        "sku"       => $item->sku, 
        "id"        => $item->id
    ); 
}

echo json_encode($items);
```

Comment: I think it can be more than 1 index in fulfillments. **Also, pay attention on Std Class Objects here**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$yourData = array();
$shippingData =array();

foreach ($yourData as $fulfillments) {
    foreach ($fulfillments->line_items as $line_items) {
        $shippingData[] = array(
            'name' => $line_items->name,
            'quantity' => $line_items->quantity,
            'sku' => $line_items->sku,
            'id' => $line_items->id
        );
    }
}

echo json_encode($shippingData);
```